# Why am I getting variable 'list' has no value?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I am trying to understand why I am getting this error, as I am fairly new to lisp. I want to create a function that takes a number `n` from the user and creates a list of up to five numbers based on that number. The function then takes the first number in the list and sends it to the end of the list.

Example

`> (my_func 1)`

`> (2 3 4 5 1)`

This is what I have so far, I am able to get the function to return a list, however I am unsure on how to send the first element to the back of the list.

```
(defun my_rotate (y)
    (labels ((var (list) (loop for i from y to list collect i)))
        (var 5) (append (rest list)(list (first list))))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by formatting the code "properly", this makes it much easier to see the structure of the code:

```
(defun my_rotate (y)
  (labels ((var (list)
             (loop for i from y to list collect i)))
    (var 5)
    (append (rest list)         ;; This form is not in a lexical context
        (list (first list)))))  ;; where list is bound
```

We can clearly see that the reason we're getting an error is because `list` simply isn't bound, so the local function `var` is not actually useful (it's called, but throws the value away, since it has no side effects, it could in theory be optimized away).

The simplest fix is to move the `append` call outside the `labels`, drop the `labels` form, then change the name of the input argument to `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear to me, but if I understand correctly, something like this should work:

```
 (defun my_rotate (y)
    (let ((list (loop for i from y to (+ 4 y) collect i)))  ;; create the list you want
       (append (rest list) (subseq list 0 1))))             ;; move first element to end
```